# elasticsearch java library- how to create this query with the QueryBuilders class

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

**QUESTION UPDATE**

I need to create the following query with Elasticsearch Java api with classes like 'QueryBuilders'.

```
  "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "range": {
                "sampletime": {
                  "gte": "now-24h",
                  "format": "epoch_second"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "instance_name:vol12 AND total_ops:<1000000000"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
"aggregations": {
        "avg": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "cl_weighted_ops"
          }
        },
        "max": {
          "max": {
            "field": "cl_weighted_ops"
          }
        },
        "median": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "cl_weighted_ops",
            "percents": [
              50
            ],
            "keyed": true,
            "tdigest": {
              "compression": 100
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm not sure I understand the way this builder work - for example, here there's a filter query, which accepts an array of conditions, but i only manage to 'insert' one condition. This is what I got:

```
    return QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("sampletime").
   gte("now-24h")).must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("instance_name", areaName)).must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("total_ops").lt(1000000000));
```

which gives me:

```
   {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "instance_name": {
                "value": "instance name",
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "total_ops": {
                "from": null,
                "to": 1000000000,
                "include_lower": true,
                "include_upper": false,
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter": [
          {
            "range": {
              "sampletime": {
                "from": "now-24h",
                "to": null,
                "include_lower": true,
                "include_upper": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1
      }
    },
   "aggregations": {
    "avg": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "cl_weighted_ops"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "max": {
          "max": {
            "field": "cl_weighted_ops"
          }
        },
        "median": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "cl_weighted_ops",
            "percents": [
              50.0
            ],
            "keyed": true,
            "tdigest": {
              "compression": 100.0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

instead of the must and range clause being **inside the filter array** they are just 'siblings' which really doesn't help me

*(the above was solved by using 'filter' instead of 'must' see comments by val)*

The aggregation also didn't work out, the avg clause should be under the second aggregation, and not where it is.

The aggregation I created like that:

```
PercentilesAggregationBuilder med = AggregationBuilders.percentiles("median").percentiles(50).field("field name");
        AvgAggregationBuilder avg = AggregationBuilders.avg("avg").field("field name");
        MaxAggregationBuilder max = AggregationBuilders.max("max").field("field name");
        
        med.subAggregation(avg).subAggregation(max);
```

Comment: You just need to replace the `must()` calls by `filter()` calls

Comment: @Val thanks! how do i append the aggregation to this? I tried something like that:
MaxAggregationBuilder field = AggregationBuilders.max("max").field("myfield");
        MaxAggregationBuilder avg = AggregationBuilders.max("avg").field("myfield");
        field.subAggregation(avg);
but its not creating it in a proper format

Comment: Please update your question as it's hard to read code in comments